# React Native - TextInput value using ref (Uncontrolled Component)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, textinput, react-ref

I wanna know if its possible to get the value from a TextInput using its ref, like this:

```
emailRef = useRef<TextInput>();

return(
   <>
       <TextInput ref={emailRef}/>
       <TouchableOpacity 
           onPress={() => console.log(emailRef.current.value)}
       >
           Print Value of TextInput
       </TouchableOpacity>
   </>
)
```

I know this is possible on React, but i don't get how to do this on React Native

**obs: I don't wanna use State to do this.**

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, by using the `emailRef.current._lastNativeText` in directly in another element.

---

I'm going to teach you a "little trick".

From my experience, the `useRef` in `TextInput`s are used more to change the current value on the Input.

To get access to the value I usually see something like this:

Adding these props / functions to the TextInput

```
 <TextInput ref={emailRef}
    ....
    onChange={ handleInputChange }. 
    onEndEditing={ handleInputSubmit }
    ....
 />
```

You can then get the input by simply

```
const handleInputChange = useCallback((ev) => {
        const inputValue = ev.nativeEvent.text
        // you can do what you want now
        ....
}
```

This might seem like extra work, but the advantage of this method is that it allows you to check for input errors (p.e. if you don't what special characters in the input) without having to use `setState` or `useEffect` everytime you type in the `TextInput`

Comment: That's useful, I will use the onEndEditing for now!

But i really wanna know if I can use the ref for get the .text, so for that reason i will not mark your answer as the correct for this problem.

Comment: you can use your answer. just change to `console.log(emailRef.current._lastNativeText)`

Comment: i got undefined when try console.log(emailRef.current._lastNativeText)

Comment: Try changing the `emailRef` initiator to     `const emailRef = useRef(null)`. I tested on a project using RN 0.61.5

Comment: That's sadly not working for me, i will drop this and will use useState :/ thanks for helping